# I cannot get .length of my li?

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I am doing my slider and somehow I want to get the .length/.size() of my li elements which contains images.

this is my code:

```
    window.onload = function slider() {
        $('#img1').show('fade', 500);
        $('#img1').delay(5000).hide("slide",{direction:'left'},500);
    }

    var length = $('li').length();
    console.log(length);
    var count = 2;
    setInterval(function () {
        $('#img' + count).show('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 500);
        $('#img' + count).delay(5500).hide('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 500);

        if (count === sc) {
            count = 1;
        } else {
            count += 1;
        }
    }, 6500);
```

I am getting this error

[image: error]

Comment: var length = $('li').length;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Length comes as a jQuery object's property so call it without ().

```
$('li').length
```

Or

```
$('li').size()
```

I see you mentioned it correctly in the first line of your question

> " I want to get the .length/.size()".

Comment: i have problem when i console.log my length, it is zero, but it had 4 li elements?

Comment: even after removing ()?

Comment: yes, my slider stops at the last image, so the if count === length [changed in my code] doesn't slide again :/, can i use it on lists element, if not, how can i display the number of my li elements?

Comment: fixed it by var all = document.getElementsByTagName('li').length; inside the function. never thought it wasn't ok, when it's declared outside the function.

Comment: good catch, but I would recommend to move the entire sliding function inside window.onload function.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery `$('li')` returns an object, that behaves like an array, with all the matched elements.

So you can use the [array.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property that represents an unsigned, 32-bit integer that is always numerically greater than the highest index in the array.

Code:

```
var length = $('ul.slider li').length;
```

Note that is intended to select only the `ul.slider li` elements.

Comment: @learningjavascriptks remember that if you have more `li` elements in your html page, the result of `$('li')` will included all of them... That's way it is recommended to use `$('ul.slider li').length` to only select the `li` elements within `ul.slider`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the function brackes

Use like this

```
 var length = $('li').length;
```

Instead of

```
var length = $('li').length();
```